# Accordion Page Layout CSS Question

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to construct a page layout that will look something like this:

[image]

In this case, A, B and C are three divs that house 100% of the page height. The goal is to construct the CSS so that A and C are static heights and B is the variable that fills the space.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What does the lower `<div>` do? Do you want it to *always* stay in that spot, or to be pushed down when **B** gets too big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the glorious [**Sticky Footer**](http://jsfiddle.net/FpZ8g/37/). Scale the preview box vertically to see what the design does.

The footer sits at the bottom of the page when the middle `<div>` doesn't push it down, but it floats down with the page when the content pushes it.

The method is a bit inelegant-looking, but it's easy to do:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="upper">Foo</div>
    <div id="middle">Foo</div>
</div>

<div id="lower">Foo</div>
```

The trick is all in the duct tape: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.

Comment: @Blender... your first fiddle doesn't work but your second fiddle does.

Comment: I'll edit my first one out. It was my failed attempt at making a sticky footer...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the other answers is that if your center content overflows, the layout blows up.  Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/JgS7f/

Comment: A sticky footer might also work. It would be nice to know the function of the lower `<div>`...

Comment: My layout doesn't blow up :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say position the rows absolutely. You didn't specify what you wanted to happen if row B content exceeded page height. Should row B get a scrollbar or should row C be pushed out of the viewport, giving body a scrollbar?

My response assumes the former.

http://jsfiddle.net/aWjr9/4/

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in php

```
<style>
.container .a{  border:1px red solid; height:100px; }

.container .b{  border:1px red solid;  }

.container .c{  border:1px red solid; height:150px;}

</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="a">
A
</div>
<div class="b" style="height:<?php echo $x;?>px;">
B
</div>
 <strong><div class="c">
C
</div></strong>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?!?!?!?

Comment: And this method doesn't give the desired results. The `<div>` in the middle doesn't fill the whole page: http://jsfiddle.net/TXkCr/

Comment: You can define the middle height at your php code example : $x = 500;

Comment: This will *not* work. The browser height is not known to PHP, and never will be. And how does this differ from manually setting the height?

Comment: This is on side server scripting better look for other answer.

Comment: You don't do layout with PHP. Sorry.